# Incorrect combobox colors with classic toolkit / material theme / dark mode

Tags: extjs

When using classic toolkit with the material theme and dark mode turned on, the combobox list appears incorrectly when expanded - you can see the effect in this fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3kkd

As you can see, the background appears as white, as well as the text. I suspect it is related to some sass variable, but have no idea where to look for it?

Answer (score 0):

The expanded list is created by `Ext.view.BoundList`,
so sass probably will be `$boundlist-background-color`

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.view.BoundList.html#css_var-S-$boundlist-background-color